# Wordpress gravity forms file format validation message

Tags: wordpress, validation, file-extension, gravity-forms-plugin

Using Gravity Forms plugin on my website projects. I have "File Upload" field with enabled Multi-File Upload. I have a list of allowed file extensions. When I'm trying to upload file with extension which is not allowed, Gravity Forms shows me error. Is it possible to change the error text to my own? I'm only interested in message which I see exactly after uploading wrong file, not after submitting. Looking for your advices. Thank you.
[Gravity Forms documentation about message changing](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_field_validation/), but I didn't understand how to change it in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

In the field settings, in appearance tab, there is an option for that : "Custom validation message".

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/file-upload/#appearance